# CloudFormation template failing to create "files" under MetaData Section

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Could somebody help me point what wrong am I doing here. I am failing to understand how the meta data part uses the authentication resource, In the AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication part I've mentioned the role same as the one attached to the instance, Yet I'm unable to create the file "some.txt"

```
{

"Parameters": {

    "SecurityGroupId": {
        "Description": "Security group for instance",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id"
    }

},


"Resources": {
    "MyInstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "configsets": {
                    "InstallIt": ["config1"]
                },

                "config1": {
                    "files": {
                        "/home/ec2-user/some.txt": {
                            "content": "This is my name ",
                            "encoding": "base64",
                            "mode": "000644",
                            "owner": "root",
                            "group": "root"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
                "HelpMe": {
                    "type": "S3",
                    "buckets": "poc-bucket",
                    "roleName": "EC2andS3"
                }

            }
        },
        "Properties": {
            "KeyName": "GoldenImage-NV-Anant",
            "DisableApiTermination": "false",
            "ImageId": "ami-0b33d91d",
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "Monitoring": "false",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-73487a59",
            "SecurityGroupIds": [{
                "Ref": "SecurityGroupId"
            }],
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Ref": "MyInstanceProfile"
            },
            "Tags": [{
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "GeicoUserDataPocInstance"
            }],
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "", [
                            "#!/bin/bash -ex \n",
                            "echo \"hello dudes\" > /home/ec2-user/hello.txt \n",
                            "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v",
                            " --stack ", {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                            },
                            " --resource MyInstance ",
                            " --configsets InstallIt ",
                            " --region ", {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            }, "\n",
                            "echo \"bye dudes\" > /home/ec2-user/bye.txt", "\n",


                            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                            "    --stack ", {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                            },
                            "    --resource MyInstance ",
                            "    --region ", {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            }, "\n"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        "CreationPolicy": {
            "ResourceSignal": {
                "Timeout": "PT90M",
                "Count": "1"
            }
        }
    },

    "MyInstanceProfile": {
        "Description": "Instance profile for the instance",
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
        "Properties": {
            "Path": "/",
            "Roles": ["EC2andS3"]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `configsets` should be [`configSets`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-configsets) with capital `S`:

  ```
  "configSets": {
      "InstallIt": ["config1"]
  },
  ```
- [`buckets`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-authentication.html#cfn-cloudformation-authentication-buckets) property needs to be a list of strings (this might not be necessary, the documentation is a bit unclear):

  ```
  "buckets": ["poc-bucket"]
  ```
- [`AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-authentication.html) resource shouldn't be necessary unless the source of your file is an S3 bucket. Even then, it still shouldn't be necessary when using an attached instance profile, since it will use the instance profile for authentication by default.